# Масштабирование объекта SVG в HTML

Tags: html, css, svg

Подскажите, как правильно объявить `svg` объект, чтобы он занял все свободного пространство экрана и при этом не "вылезал" вниз. Например у меня есть svg:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" baseProfile="full" height="1088px" style="background:#FFFFFF" version="1.1" width="1088px">
  <defs>
    <style type="text/css">
        .default_default {
          fill: #E4801B;
          stroke: #000000;
          stroke-width: 1.0px;
        }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <g id="root" transform="translate(0,0)">
   <g id="Auto" class="default_default" transform=" translate(0,0) rotate(0,32,32)">
    <g id="layer0">
   <rect y="24" x="0" height="16" width="64" id="c0trumpet"/>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g id="Auto" class="default_default" transform=" translate(576,576) rotate(0,32,32)">
    <g id="layer0">
   <rect y="24" x="0" height="16" width="64" id="c1trumpet"/>
    </g>
   </g>
   <!-- тут еще 14 групп с id="Auto"-->
   <g id="Auto" class="default_default" transform=" translate(960,960) rotate(0,32,32)">
    <g id="layer0">
   <rect y="24" x="0" height="16" width="64" id="c15trumpet"/>
    </g>
   </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Auto.html выглядит следующим образом:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="menu">
        <a href="Auto.html">Untitled</a>
        <div>
            <object id="AutoId" type="image/svg+xml" data="Auto.svg"></object>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Auto.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Таким образом я получаю страницу, которая представлена на рисунке 1. 
[image: Рисунок 1 - Как выглядит сейчас]
Как видно, не вся svg поместилась на страницу. А хотелось бы получить результат как на второй картинке, т.е. уместить всю svg в область под Untitled так, чтобы вниз страница не прокручивалась.
[image: Рисунок 2 - Как хотелось бы получить]

Comment: viewBox вместо width и height

Comment: @ioprst Добро пожаловать на stackoverflow! Очень хорошо, что вы оформили подробно свой ответ. На такие вопросы и отвечать подробно приятно.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT завтра буду на работе, обязательно проверю все ваши советы. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @ioprst а разве  здесь не видно, что всё работает? Завтра я тоже буду на работе, в командировке, и если у вас появятся, какие-то вопросы, я не смогу на них ответить. Проверьте и спросите лучше сегодня :))

Comment: @Alexandr_TT попробовал сейчас открыть страничку с svg после ваших манипуляций, все равно прокрутка осталась :(. Что касается оптимизации svg, соглашусь, но (оправдаюсь) я не создаю сам svg, я ее генерирую с помощью шаблонов и поэтому возникают записи типа rotate(0,32,32) - элемент не поворачивался.

Comment: @ ioprst ну я же специально написал в ответе - "Повторюсь: Чтобы убедиться, что svg не выходит за рамки дисплея браузера (нет полос прокрутки) - скачайте файл и смотрите его на локальном ПК, без искажений масштабирования, которые вносит сниппет сайта. " Я проверил это, прежде чем давать ответ на своем локальном ПК

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, Я скачивал. Добавил свой ответ с полученными результатами в тему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Масштабирование SVG файла

- Если вам нужно, чтобы svg изображение с размерами `width="1088"` и
  `height="1088"` занимало весь экран и не выходило за его рамки, то
  необходимо указывать ширину и высоту `100%` в шапке svg файла -
  `width="100%"` `height="100%"` и добавить `viewBox="0 0 1088 1088"`

  - Для наглядности я добавил стиль - `style="border:1px solid red;"` - это
    будет красная рамка, которая чётко показывает границы SVG
    изображения.

Ниже код вашего svg файла с измененной шапкой, как написано выше:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"   width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1088 1088"  style="border:1px solid red;">
  <defs>
    <style type="text/css">
        .default_default {
          fill: #E4801B;
          stroke: #000000;
          stroke-width: 1.0px;
        }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <g id="root" transform="translate(0,0)">
   <g id="Auto" class="default_default" transform=" translate(0,0) rotate(0,32,32)">
    <g id="layer0">
   <rect y="24" x="0" height="16" width="64" id="c0trumpet" />
    </g>
   </g>
   <g id="Auto" class="default_default" transform=" translate(576,576) rotate(0,32,32)">
    <g id="layer0">
   <rect y="24" x="0" height="16" width="64" id="c1trumpet"/>
    </g>
   </g>
   <!-- тут еще 14 групп с id="Auto"-->
   <g id="Auto" class="default_default" transform=" translate(960,960) rotate(0,32,32)">
    <g id="layer0">
   <rect y="24" x="0" height="16" width="64" id="c15trumpet"/>
    </g>
   </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

**Здесь в сниппете не видно, но если вы откроете этот файл локально на своем ПК, то будет заметно, что svg занимает весь экран без полос прокрутки.**

Но изображение не прижато к левому углу дисплея. Это происходит, из-за того, что задан квадрат 1088х1088, а окно браузера прямоугольное.

- Чтобы прижать изображение к левому верхнему углу, необходимо добавить
  ещё один параметр в шапку svg файла: `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin  meet"`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="100%" height="100%"
viewBox="0 0 1088 1088" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"  
style="border:1px solid red;" >
  <defs>
    <style type="text/css">
        .default_default {
          fill: #E4801B;
          stroke: #000000;
          stroke-width: 1.0px;
        }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <g id="root" transform="translate(0,0)">
   <g id="Auto" class="default_default" transform=" translate(0,0) rotate(0,32,32)">
    <g id="layer0">
   <rect y="24" x="0" height="16" width="64" id="c0trumpet" />
    </g>
   </g>
   <g id="Auto" class="default_default" transform=" translate(576,576) rotate(0,32,32)">
    <g id="layer0">
   <rect y="24" x="0" height="16" width="64" id="c1trumpet"/>
    </g>
   </g>
   <!-- тут еще 14 групп с id="Auto"-->
   <g id="Auto" class="default_default" transform=" translate(960,960) rotate(0,32,32)">
    <g id="layer0">
   <rect y="24" x="0" height="16" width="64" id="c15trumpet"/>
    </g>
   </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

### Оптимизация кода SVG

```
 <g id="root" transform="translate(0,0)">
      <g id="Auto" class="default_default" transform=" translate(0,0) rotate(0,32,32)">
          <g id="layer0">
            <rect y="24" x="0" height="16" width="64" id="c0trumpet"/>
          </g>
      </g>
```

- Код явно избыточен,- две пары групповых тегов `<g>` c ненужными
  идентификаторами  Причем такой код будет повторятся много раз.
- Команда `rotate(0,32,32)` лишняя, какой смысл поворачивать
  прямоугольник на нулевой угол?
- от команды `transform="translate(X Y)"` тоже можно освободиться

Взамен можно объявить прямоугольник `rect` один раз в секции `<defs>` и затем его многократно клонировать с помощью команды `<use>`  .

`<defs>
<rect id="rec"  height="16" width="64"  /> 
</defs> 
<use xlink:href="#rec" x="10" y="24" /> 
   <use xlink:href="#rec" x="74" y="84" />`

*Ниже полный код вашего примера*

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" baseProfile="full"  style="border:1px solid red" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1088 1088" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >
  <defs>
    <style type="text/css">
        #rec {
          fill: #E4801B;
          stroke: #000000;
          stroke-width: 1.0px;
        }
    </style>
  <rect id="rec"  height="16" width="64"  />
  </defs>
   <use xlink:href="#rec" x="10" y="24" /> 
   <use xlink:href="#rec" x="74" y="84" /> 
   <use xlink:href="#rec" x="138" y="144" />
   <use xlink:href="#rec" x="202" y="204" />
   <use xlink:href="#rec" x="266" y="264" /> 
   <use xlink:href="#rec" x="330" y="324" /> 
   <use xlink:href="#rec" x="394" y="384" />  
   <use xlink:href="#rec" x="458" y="444" /> 
   <use xlink:href="#rec" x="522" y="504" /> 
   <use xlink:href="#rec" x="586" y="564" /> 
   <use xlink:href="#rec" x="650" y="624" /> 
   <use xlink:href="#rec" x="714" y="684" /> 
   <use xlink:href="#rec" x="778" y="744" /> 
   <use xlink:href="#rec" x="842" y="804" /> 
   <use xlink:href="#rec" x="906" y="864" /> 
   <use xlink:href="#rec" x="970" y="924" /> 
   <use xlink:href="#rec" x="1034" y="984" /> 
    
</svg>
```

за позиционирование элементов отвечают координаты X Y команды `<use>`

**Повторюсь:** Чтобы убедиться, что svg не выходит за рамки дисплея браузера (нет полос прокрутки) - скачайте файл и смотрите его на локальном ПК, без искажений масштабирования, которые вносит сниппет сайта.

### Добавление `SVG` в `HTML`

Пока вы не набрались опыта работы с SVG, лучше использовать инлайн добавление в HTML.

Для этого оборачиваем svg код в `<div id="container">`

```html
<style>
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
</style>
<div class="container" >
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" baseProfile="full"  style="border:1px solid red" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1088 1088" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >
  <defs>
    <style type="text/css">
        #rec {
          fill: #E4801B;
          stroke: #000000;
          stroke-width: 1.0px;
        }
    </style>
  <rect id="rec"  height="16" width="64"  />
  </defs>
   <use xlink:href="#rec" x="10" y="24" /> 
   <use xlink:href="#rec" x="74" y="84" /> 
   <use xlink:href="#rec" x="138" y="144" />
   <use xlink:href="#rec" x="202" y="204" />
   <use xlink:href="#rec" x="266" y="264" /> 
   <use xlink:href="#rec" x="330" y="324" /> 
   <use xlink:href="#rec" x="394" y="384" />  
   <use xlink:href="#rec" x="458" y="444" /> 
   <use xlink:href="#rec" x="522" y="504" /> 
   <use xlink:href="#rec" x="586" y="564" /> 
   <use xlink:href="#rec" x="650" y="624" /> 
   <use xlink:href="#rec" x="714" y="684" /> 
   <use xlink:href="#rec" x="778" y="744" /> 
   <use xlink:href="#rec" x="842" y="804" /> 
   <use xlink:href="#rec" x="906" y="864" /> 
   <use xlink:href="#rec" x="970" y="924" /> 
   <use xlink:href="#rec" x="1034" y="984" /> 
    
</svg>
</div>
```

Изменяя проценты ширины и высоты контейнера svg, вы можете получить любые размеры. 
 **Приложение будет адаптивно и работает во всех браузерах.**

Answer (score 1):

Возможно кому-то пригодится еще один вариант решения.
svg шапка:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" baseProfile="full" height="100%" style="background:#31C184" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1088 1088" width="100%">
```

И html с js

```js
window.onload = function() {
    svgDoc = document.getElementById("AutoId").contentDocument;
    var timer = setInterval(anim, 100);
    var timerPost = setInterval(setPost, 100);
    initClick();
    updateSize();
}

window.onresize = updateSize;

function updateSize() {
    vpW = document.getElementsByClassName('main')[0].clientWidth;
    vpH = document.getElementsByClassName('main')[0].clientHeight;
    //imgW = document.getElementsByClassName('box content')[0].clientWidth;
    //imgH = document.getElementsByClassName('box content')[0].clientHeight;
    imgW = 1088;
    imgH = 1088;
    //alert(vpW + ':' + vpH + ' = ' + vpW/vpH + '      ' + imgW + ':' + imgH + ' = ' + imgW/imgH);

    if(vpW/vpH < imgW/imgH) {
        for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            document.getElementsByClassName('horizontalbar')[i].style.height = (vpH - vpW)/2 + 'px';
            document.getElementsByClassName('box sidebar')[i].style.width = '0px';
        }
    } else {
        for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            document.getElementsByClassName('box sidebar')[i].style.width = (vpW - vpH)/2 + 'px';
            document.getElementsByClassName('horizontalbar')[i].style.height = '0px'
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>testPrj</title>
    <style>
        .wrapper {
          height: 100%;
          display: table;
          width: 100%;
        }

        .header {
          display: table-row;
          height: 1px;
        }

        .main {
          height: 100%;
          display: table;
          width: 100%;
        }

        .horizontalbar {
          display: table-row;
          height: 0px;
        }

        .box {
          display: table-cell;
        }

        .sidebar {
          width: 0px;
        }

        .content {
          height: 100%;
        }

        .content iframe {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          border: none;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          display: block;
        }

        .footer {
          display: table-row;
          height:1px;
        }

        /* Basic Style*/
        * { margin:0; padding:0;}
        html, body {
          height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffff00">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <button onclick='location.href="Auto.html"'>Auto</button>
        <button onclick='location.href="Auto1.html"'>Auto1</button>
      </div>

      <div class="main">
        <div class="horizontalbar"></div>
        <div class="box sidebar"></div>
        <div class="box content">
          <iframe frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="Auto.svg" id="AutoId"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="box sidebar"></div>
        <div class="horizontalbar"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">Text. Text</div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Auto.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Адекватно работает только для квадратных svg.

Comment: вы взяли не тот пример из моего ответа. Я просто пытался вам поэтапно объяснить, как происходит масштабирование. Возьмите пример из последнего раздела - **"Добавление SVG в HTML"** И пока у вас мало опыта не связывайтесь с `<object>`,- добавляйте svg  в HTML инлайн, как у меня в примере.

Comment: @ Alexandr_TT, а через object это реализовать не получится? Ведь мне бы хотелось в итоге управлять данной svg через JS. И это уже работает, проблема только в масштабировании)

Comment: можно и так и так, всё зависит от вашего опыта. Просто inline svg, проще в управлении, в том числе и проще для доступа JS к элементам SVG и ещё один фактор - у `Chrome` после обновлений появились баги в обработке `<object>` Надеюсь, что они их исправят, а пока лучше inline SVG

Comment: @ Alexandr_TT, подправил свой ответ. Использовал пример из "Добавление SVG в HTML". Все равно не помещается.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHG1A.png  убрал `<!DOCTYPE html>` и всё стало умещаться в окне браузера/ В современных браузерах не обязательно указывать  `<!DOCTYPE html>`